# what would this line of command do? grep ^..[l-z]$ hello.txt

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, grep

I am wondering what would this line of command do:
 grep ^..[l-z]$ hello.txt 
I know grep but I don't know what is this part " ^..[I-z]$ " do?

I am using Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: Probably better suited for [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com) or [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command will search only for the line which contains 3 Alphanumeric characters from start to last in which the last character belongs to l to z.
 see below example -

```
cat hello.txt 
hello vipin
..l
1ll
1la
abl
 ..l
#.z
1.a
..l..
..vipin

grep ^..[l-z]$ hello.txt
..l
1ll
abl
#.z
```

Answer (score 0):

it searches all lines that are build of exactly 3 letters where the last is one of l through z